# What is the significance of the recommended height of a custom fighter?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

When customizing a fighter in Soul Calibur 5, upon choosing your preferred weapon (or soul), the next prompt is for the height of your character. There are 5 choices, and one of them is selected by default and marked with a star. This default height is different for different weapons, and the text claims something about that being the "optimal" height for fighters of that weapon.

What does this mean? What does height affect, gameplay wise? What downsides are there for picking a height other than the recommended one?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this has to do with setting the size of your actual hitbox, but it's got to have something to do with weapon damage and/or reach, otherwise the smallest would be the best choice. Good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bigger characters have a longer reach and less power.   Smaller characters have shorter reach and more power.    The optimal setting is the size of the character who uses that specific fighting style.  (i.e. if you create a character with Voldo's style and choose the optimal height, that character would have the same reach and power as Voldo in arcade mode.)

Comment: Do you have any more information on this? Either testing in training mode, or a source? How much of a difference does this make?

Answer (score 0):

I think simply put the recommended height is the original height of the character you picked to model your new character after.